# Spring Configuration to authorize only one URL

Tags: java, configuration, jwt

I want to authorize only one URL in my application for eg: /hello using JWT token. I want to allow rest all methods to go through without any authentication. Can someone please help me figure out what should I have in my config file for this to work?

Below is what I have currently

```
http.anonymous().disable().antMatcher("/hello").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority("myscope")
            .and().addFilterBefore(oauthApiFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to allow only "/hello" endpoints,

```
httpSecurity.antMatcher("/hello").authorizeRequests()
        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().addFilterBefore(oauthApiFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable();
```